# Hide Image in Directory and All its subs from Appearing in Gallery in Android

Tags: android

How can I hide image from appearing in Gallery in Android. I need to hide image in one directory and all its sub directories, so it is difficult to add .nomedia file to each folder, and can't change files or folders name
Any other solution?

Comment: Put the image in [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html) for your app. There is no requirement for a gallery app to ignore directories with `.nomedia` files in them.

Comment: I can't change the image locations

Comment: Then you will have to settle for some apps still showing the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did make an andriod application that can do this
https://github.com/Salehd1979/HideImages